# IcCube Reporting : How to stop drill in a hierarchy?

Tags: mdx, iccube, iccube-reporting

When we query a dimension/hierarchy with multiple levels, the drill is by default allowed thru all the levels of that hierarchy...
For example, in a hierarchy made of : `Continent/Country/State/City`.

What is the solution to restrict the drill to the State level (i.e. not showing the city level) without having to create a new hierarchy without City ?

I heard that this can be done using fonctions in the schema scripts to "flatten" the hierarchy.

Can someone give me a live example of that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is mapping our navigation as an MDX function (you could also copy&paste the code but there is no reuse). Somethink like this (Sales example) :

```
CREATE FUNCTION navigationDemo(_x) AS 
            {
            CASE  
            WHEN _x.hierarchy is [Customers].[Geography] THEN [Product].[Product].[Category]
            WHEN _x.hierarchy is [Product].[Product] THEN [Time].[Year].[Year]
            ELSE {}
            END
            }
```

Once this is done we can go to our widget, in our example a table, and define a Drilldown Strategy. It should be of type mdxExpression and we can insert into the MDX Expression our newly created function

```
navigationDemo( $member )   // where $member is the clicked member in the table
```

Do no forget to set the 'Filter by' as we want the new data to be filtered by the clicked member.

[image]